# PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/webview

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I have tryed the next three package for the web view in my flutter widget:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter
2. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview
3. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin

But always have the same error. The error is the next:

```
E/flutter (20538): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/webview
E/flutter (20538):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:97)
E/flutter (20538):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:95)
E/flutter (20538):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/flutter (20538):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:226)
E/flutter (20538):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (20538):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:631)
E/flutter (20538):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (20538):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter (20538):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/flutter (20538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/flutter (20538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (20538):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/flutter (20538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/flutter (20538): , null)
E/flutter (20538): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter (20538): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter (20538): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20538): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter (20538): #3      AndroidViewController._create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:633:54)
E/flutter (20538): #4      AndroidViewController.setSize (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:550:14)
E/flutter (20538): #5      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:175:29)
E/flutter (20538): #6      RenderAndroidView.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:156:5)
E/flutter (20538): #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1746:9)
E/flutter (20538): #8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
E/flutter (20538): #9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #10     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
E/flutter (20538): #11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #12     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:808:17)
E/flutter (20538): #13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #14     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:11)
E/flutter (20538): #15     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:484:7)
E/flutter (20538): #16     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
E/flutter (20538): #17     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:399:14)
E/flutter (20538): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
E/flutter (20538): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
E/flutter (20538): #22     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1248:11)
E/flutter (20538): #23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
E/flutter (20538): #25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
E/flutter (20538): #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
E/flutter (20538): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter (20538): #30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (packa
```

I have also tryed to change minSdkVersion 20 but have the same error, which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25714).

This is my 'flutter doctor -v'

```
/Users/taz/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.17.0-3.2.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-GE)
    • Flutter version 1.17.0-3.2.pre at /Users/taz/Desktop/flutter
    • Framework revision 2a7bc389f2 (3 days ago), 2020-04-21 20:34:20 -0700
    • Engine revision 4c8c31f591
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.20.10)

Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/taz/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.3

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

What I can do? :)

Answer (score 6):

Run flutter clean, and restart the application on your emulator. After this, the plugin started to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)! Latest release is `3.3.0+3` at the time of this writing.
It has a lot of new events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

Comment: I am using the latest flutter_inappwebview: ^4.0.0+4 but I face the above issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the full plugin from the Github repository and made corrections in accordance with the `example/lib/main.dart` file.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same here......

In my case, Inside AndroidManifest.xml file,this line was missing inside <activity (android:name=".MainActivity") .

Therefore I added this  android:name=".MainActivity" and my issue solved